# Proper way to refer to a makom ervah when speaking to a child

Tags: children-parenting, speech-talking

When speaking to my young son about his makom ha'ervah I have referred to it as his "bris". What would be a proper, lashon naki, term to use when speaking to my young daughter about her makom ha'ervah (until now we have referred to her 'private area' but she wants to know what the Jewish name is). The actual term "makom ervah" seems to be too hard for her to remember.

Comment: Why is 'bris' easier to remember than 'ervah'?

Comment: ....just fyi, I understand that modesty is important, but many parents are choosing to teach their kids the medical names for these things so that if, G-d forbid, they are victims of abuse, the kids can describe what happened to adults.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman - You don't need explicit anatomical terminology to describe these things; a euphemism will work just fine, as long as it's specific enough.

Comment: @Dave, anatomical terminology is not "explicit" in the sense of inappropriate. It is "explicit" in the sense that it does not avoid using the proper vernacular, but that should not be assumed to be the same as the other understanding of the word "explicit", either in definition of the word or in how one reacts to it. What I mean to say is, what makes the scientific name of the thing wrong to teach children?

Comment: I completely agree with @SethJ. There are plenty of other slang and vulgar words that exist, but scientific terminology is not that.

Comment: DoubleAA and @SethJ - this might be a cultural thing. Where I come from, those "scientific" words are *never* mentioned in conversation, and would be considered borderline nivul peh. Can you explain why specific euphemisms are not sufficient to address the concern raised by CharlesKoppelman?

Comment: @Dave - when someone who isn't the parent is, G-d forbid, asking the child where the person touched them, it's nice for them to be able to tell people.

Comment: @Dave but I do understand wanting to avoid anatomical terms.  I was put off the first time I heard the idea....

Comment: @Dave I can't speak for anyone else, but I think that discussing these things in scientific language adds a sense of professionalism and seriousness to the discussion. You wouldn't expect your doctor to use various euphemisms even if they aren't vulgar, because he is a professional. And it's that air of formality and sobriety that is in my mind the best antidote to what could have been _nivul pe_.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience it is called אותו מקום, *oto makom* - "that place"