# Is there a problem for a Jew to say the word "penis"?

Tags: hebrew, parts-of-the-body, english

There appear to be some sources that claim that Lashon Ha'kodesh is holy because there are no words in the language for the male or female genitalia. Instead the word "yerech" (thigh), "raglayim" (legs), "eiver" (limb), "oso makom" (that place) and other such clue words are used. If someone is speaking English, is there any reason for him to avoid using the actual words for the male or female genitalia?

Comment: Rambam said it's called lashon hakodesh because there is no word specifically designated for human copulation.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14257/759

Comment: less possibly dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18281/759

Comment: How do you know that "raglayim" is used for the genitalia (I only saw it used regarding urine, and nothing else)? Another example of the male organ would be "ama" (the name of the middle finger (might be the source of the use of the middle finger) and the name of the distance between the tip of the middle finger until the elbow)

Comment: @user6591 did you mean to imply that Maimonides writes that there is no reason to avoid saying the words for the reproductive *organs*, only the *act* of copulation?

Comment: @Reb Chaim. No. There may be many reasons not to say that word, along with many others. However the reason given for the specific title Lashon Hakodesh was only since there is no specific word for copulation.